# Wileyfox Swift won't turn on

Tags: battery, hardware, reboot, power-on, troubleshooting

My WileyFox Swift phone's battery somehow emptied itself overnight and now the phone won't turn on at all.

Battery is 68% full. When I plug the charger cable in/out the phone vibrates and the Wileyfox logo appears as well as the battery icon but no other reaction whether connected or not. I always download the latest Android updates and regularly delete photos/videos to free up storage space. I don't drop it often, screen is not broken or anything and I didn't dowload anything dodgy.

Any idea what's going wrong there and how to fix it?

What I tried without success:

- long pressing power button to provoke a restart/boot
- long-pressing power button while phone both connected and disconnected to USB charger cable - nothing.
- removed battery, microSD and SIM as well as SIM2 and put them back several times – no change.

when charging, the LED light is on, so something must be working right?

I tweeted support for help. I have limited knowledge on all things phone and so I haven't tried anything else.

Please help. This is the best phone I've had and I love it. I don't have any back-up phone so I'd appreciate if this could be troubleshooted online!
Thank you.

Comment: Friend suggested to press power button 10 times quickly and then long-press power. It worked, but it's a bit buggy, the alarm clock rings for no reason and "System UI app" was not working so I had to close it? It seems ok now. How to avoid this in future, please?

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late for you, but in case others stumble across this page while seeking help, like I did.....

I had a similar problem and contacted them via their chat function on their website.  I was advised to hold both the power and the volume down buttons for 30 seconds.  This brought up the android recovery screen - I followed the instructions and the phone is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My phone kept restarting because of empty battery. The red light was flashing but it didn't charging. I pressed volume down and power button ant it opened recovery mode. I left phone around 10 minutes and when I came back, battery charge level was18%. Then I restart phone and it worked.